# MSSQL Query for my chat site not working. Please look into it

Tags: sql, sql-server, chat

I am building a chat site and for presenting the chats to the audiences, I have 3 Dropdownlists - Sports (Default is All Sports), Day/Month/Year, Users online/Total Users.

Now, if by default all sports is selected and I pick 1 month and Total users, the expected result should be

```
Chatroom name   Total Users   Online users               

Basketball
Roomname27          32              5
Roomname11          15              3
Roomname32           8              1 

Football
Roomname5           63              12
Roomname18          44               7
Roomname4           15               2
```

My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT roo.[Sports], 
                roo.[Name], 
                COUNT(DISTINCT chu.ChatUserLogId) AS TotalUsers, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT liu.[LoggedInUserID]) AS UserOnline

 FROM Room AS roo 

 LEFT JOIN LoggedInUser AS liu ON roo.RoomID = liu.RoomID 
 LEFT JOIN ChatUserLog AS chu ON roo.RoomID = chu.RoomID 
               AND chu.LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) 

 GROUP BY roo.[Sports], roo.[Name]   
 ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

And the table and their columns are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Room] (
            [RoomID]        INT           IDENTITY (6666, 1) NOT NULL,
            [Name]          VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
            [Sports]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
            [CreatedDate]   DATETIME      DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
            [CreatedBy]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
            [CreatedUserID] INT           NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoomID] ASC)
        );


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChatUserLog] (
    [ChatUserLogId] BIGINT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MId]           INT      NOT NULL,
    [RoomId]        INT      NOT NULL,
    [LoggedInTime]  DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [LogOutTime]    DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ChatUserLogId] ASC)
);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoggedInUser] (
    [LoggedInUserID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MId]            INT           NOT NULL,
    [RoomID]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [NickName]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Icon]           VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LoggedInUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoggedInUserID] ASC)
);
```

For this above query, say, if I have 7 chatoom topics in Basketball, I get Basketball's any 3 rooms shown & the whole Basketball is repeated 7 times (Not sorted properly to my expectation too) and similary, if I have 15 chatroom topics in Football, I get whole Football repeated 15 times without getting sorted properly too.

What are the mistakes, I have done here? Thanks in advance and have a nice day ahead.

Comment: Tag c# here is not needed !

Comment: I too thought that but there are no relevant tags available and so I had to pick them. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Add your sample output

Comment: **@Vicky_Thinking** I don't have much knowledge in SQL. Could you correct the query for me? Thanks

Comment: I've seen this question before, commented on it, and you deleted it.

Comment: **@Nick.McDermaid** Sorry, I had to... Since the issue was not solved yet and I am in a hurry to finish this off, I put it again. Could you help me solve it this time, plz? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well with your method you are actually multiplying the row because of the two joins.

So you need to aggregate first, then join.

So in the end :

```
with agg_ChatUserLog as (
 select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_tot
 from ChatUserLog
 group by RoomId),
agg_LoggedInUser as (
 select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_logged
 from LoggedInUser
 group by RoomId)
select name, cnt_user_tot, cnt_user_logged
from Room r
left outer join agg_ChatUserLog acu on acu.RoomId = r.RoomId
left outer join agg_LoggedInUser alu on alu.RoomId = r.RoomId
```

Comment: And where to add "AND chu.LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) "? Thanks

Comment: In the CTE agg_LoggedInUser

Comment: **@Nemeros**  50% working fine when cnt_user_tot &  cnt_user_logged are Zero.                                                                                     "with agg_ChatUserLog as (select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_tot from ChatUserLog WHERE LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) group by RoomId), agg_LoggedInUser as (select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_logged from LoggedInUser group by RoomId) select Sports, Name, cnt_user_tot, cnt_user_logged from Room r left outer join agg_ChatUserLog acu on acu.RoomId = r.RoomId left outer join agg_LoggedInUser alu on alu.RoomId = r.RoomId";

Comment: **@Nemeros** When any of the Sport's Chatrooms have cnt_user_tot & cnt_user_logged values, then it's getting multiplied as before.  Kindly help me where I am still making the mistakes? I am not good with MSSQL.

Comment: If roomId is the primary key of the table room, then my query won't make output multiply. The group by expression in each CTE assure you that you will have maximum 1 row per roomId.

Comment: But when there is any "online users" (Cnt_user_logged), its still getting multiplied now. Also not getting sorted up properly. The top 3 chatrooms with highest number of total users should come at the top. But it ain't working too.

Comment: Well, give input test data and output. For me the query should work as intended. So i might not have understood all your requierement

Comment: Please refer the Table Schema and Sample data in the question. If you need anything else than those, let me know. I ll provide. Thanks

Comment: Ah i see, my bad. The term "football" will be multiplied for each line. I won't provide support for that part till, for me, it's not the DBMS who is in charge for the display part of the record. My Query provide support to have accurate count for each room. A easy bypass would be to use a rollup or grouping sets https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, if Football's top 3 chatrooms have any online users at that moment, it get repeated fully over n number of times (getting multiplied). My Coder is using SELECT DISTINCT[Sports], ISNULL((SELECT SUM(usr) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) From ChatUserLog WHERE RoomId = a.RoomId AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) From LoggedInUser WHERE RoomID = a.RoomID), 0) Usr From [Room] a WHERE Sports = b.Sports) as Total), 0) tot FROM [Room] b ORDER BY tot DESC to get another Dropdown's items sorted and listed fine.